# Apply rolling window and return stacked feature vectors as DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is is possible to transform a series into a data frame by applying a rolling window, calculate a feature vector and us this as a row for the resulting data frame?

For the example below, if I use `apply()` I can only return a `float` which will result in another, transformed series. However, I'd like to calculate e.g. the `fft` and stack each `fft` result to a data frame for each time step I shift a rolling window.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

N = 1000
ls = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N)
s = np.sin(10*ls) + np.sin(2*ls) + np.sin(6*ls) + 0.2*np.random.rand(N)

df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=['signal'])

def my_fft(s):
    return np.abs(np.fft.fft(s))[:int(len(s)/2)]

# This works but it feels like a hack ..
l = list()

def test(x):
    l.append(my_fft(x.copy()))
    return np.sum(x)

df.signal.rolling(100).apply(lambda x: test(x))

df_fft = pd.DataFrame(l).T

sns.heatmap(df_fft)
```

`df_fft` has in each row the FFT result of a respective window. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What would be more useful is if you provided sample data and tell us what you expect to get out of it

Comment: @piRSquared `df.signal` is the sample data. I want to calculate a rolling fft and receive the resulting matrix (preferably as DataFrame). I know how I can do this using loops but I wonder if there is a `pandas` way to do this.

Comment: @BradSolomon Well more or less. It is a solution but not really a pandas-only solution which is what I was looking for. To me this looks like as if `pandas.DataFrame` is basically missing an `apply_along_axis()` function. However, you mention that this is a deficiency of pandas so at this point in time there's probably no pandas-only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a deficiency of pandas in my opinion.  The issue is that the `func` parameter to `DataFrame.rolling.apply`

> Must produce a single value from an ndarray input

The NumPy implementation below will get you rolling windows by expanding the dimensionality of your input array `a`.  If you pass `df.signal`, which has shape (1000,), and specify a window of 100, you get a result that is of shape (901,100), or 901 windows of length 100 each.  It's been floating around on Stack Overflow for a while and I made some slight modifications below.

```
def rolling_windows(a, window):    
    if window > a.shape[0]:
        raise ValueError('Specified `window` length of {0} exceeds length of'
                         ' `a`, {1}.'.format(window, a.shape[0])) 
    if isinstance(a, (Series, DataFrame)):
        a = a.values
    if a.ndim == 1:
        a = a.reshape(-1, 1)
    shape = (a.shape[0] - window + 1, window) + a.shape[1:]
    strides = (a.strides[0],) + a.strides
    windows = np.squeeze(np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, 
                                                         strides=strides))
    # In cases where window == len(a), we actually want to "unsqueeze" to 2d.
    #     I.e., we still want a "windowed" structure with 1 window.
    if windows.ndim == 1:
        windows = np.atleast_2d(windows)
    return windows
```

You can then use `np.apply_along_axis` on the result.  Full disclosure, you could technically call this a glorified for-loop,but it tends to be pretty fast.

With your example:

```
# np.random.seed(123)
df_fft = np.apply_along_axis(my_fft, 1, rolling_windows(df.signal, window=100))
df_fft = pd.DataFrame(df_fft, index=df.index[100-1:])
# df_fft.shape == (901, 50)
```